# Create Event-drivers in PHP

Tags: php

My class:

```
classMyClassEvent
{
   public function afterTest()
   {
       echo 'After Test';
   }
   public function beforeTest()
   {
      echo 'Before Test';
   }
}

class MyClass
{
   public function test()
   {
      echo 'Test';
   }
}

$m=new MyClass;
$m->test();
```

now, i want when call function test(), systems would call to function afterTest() the first, next would call to function test() and final would call to function beforeTest().
desired results are:

```
"After Test"
"Test"
"Before Test"
```

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
class MyClassEvent {

   public function afterTest() {
     echo 'After Test';
   }

  public function beforeTest() {
  echo 'Before Test';
  }
}

class MyClass extends MyClassEvent {
  
  public function test() {
    echo $this->beforeTest();
    echo 'Test';
    echo $this->afterTest();
  }
}

$m=new MyClass;
$m->test();
```

**output**

```
Before TestTestAfter Test
```

You can use [Object Inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

> Inheritance is a well-established programming principle, and PHP makes use of this principle in its object model. This principle will affect the way many classes and objects relate to one another.
>
> For example, when you extend a class, the subclass inherits all of the public and protected methods from the parent class. Unless a class overrides those methods, they will retain their original functionality.
>
> This is useful for defining and abstracting functionality, and permits the implementation of additional functionality in similar objects without the need to reimplement all of the shared functionality.

Comment: but i don't want call after and beforeTest function inside test function, any ideas?

Comment: `$n=new  MyClassEvent;$m=new MyClass;$n->beforeTest();$m->test();$n->afterTest();` you have to call in some moment, the method wont execute by magic